# Need to script User Experience preference to "Create mobile account at login"

Tags: macos, terminal, preferences

In brief, I'm working for an organization where we support a school's infrastructure with JAMF Casper. All the Macs are bound to a Windows AD.

Currently, we have the student accounts stored on a network volume share, and they load on login, as the Macs are not set to create mobile accounts at login. This is not the recommended way to do it, and for good reason, as it causes problems.

We want to change the preferences on all the Macs in a smart group to choose "Create mobile account at login" so that the students will have managed mobile accounts when they log on, cached on the HD as is normally done. They'll be saving their work to a network volume, anyway, so it's not necessary to always load their profiles from a volume share going forward.

Is there a way to make this change through terminal commands which can be scripted, wrapped up in a JAMF login?

For that matter, I wonder if there isn't a repository of all the methods for changing any and all MacOS preferences via the terminal? Such a manual resource seems like it would very nice to have